# Rewrite & in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So i am having a rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^list-(.*)\.html$ list.html?user=$1
```

This is working fine, something like `list-username.html = list.html?user=username`

The issue is with usernames that are having & in their name.
I've tried to encode the url, using something like `list-test%26user.html` but is resulting in `list.html?user=test&user`

Any suggestions how should i encode the url in order for this to work?

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention, list.html?user=test%26user works just fine, so i need to somehow redirect it properly without decoding the url.

Comment: which characters can username contains? is & character acceptable?

Comment: yes @R.CanserYanbakan, it is.